# Find reason of high CPU usage

Tags: windows-7

I have a very strange picture in laptop [ASUS K53SC](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K53SC/) running Windows 7 SP1 64 bit: first CPU core is always loaded:

[image: first core]

But in list of processes I can see that System+Idle = 100%

[image: process list]

How is that possible? Is there a way to find the reason?

**Update:**
Looks like this time is consumed by some driver

[image]

**Update2:**

This particular problem was resolved by uninstalling WiFi driver and install another WiFi driver. The driver that does not generate high CPU load was found in CD that was shipped with the laptop.

**Update3:**
After more than a year of looking for reason it was discovered that most probably the problem was caused by some water get into the laptop. I have now clue how was it possible, but there are signs of dried droplet inside. I gave the laptop to a hardware guy, he opened it, cleared the motherboard carefully and problem gone forever. Anyway this procedure is to be done once per two years.

Comment: Use the Resource Monitor button. Task Manager adds Interrupt and DPC processing to the System Idle Process.

Comment: How about a better task manager ? Download Process Hacker and then post images. Also run resmon (Ressource Monitor) it will give you more details.

Comment: run xperf to see the high CPU usage: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140264

Comment: @DavidMarshall, I'd like to grant correct answer to you, if you post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task Manager misleadingly adds the CPU time for Interrupts and DPCs to the System Idle Process. To see the time used by Interrupts use the Resource monitor button and inspect the CPU tab. Alternatively, use a better tool such as [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

To get to the root cause you may need to use the Windows Performance Toolkit. Magicandre1981 has a [tutorial](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/) on using this.

The Windows Performance Toolkit can be obtained from the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx) or the [Windows ADK](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/11/23/installing-the-windows-performance-toolkit-v5-0-wprui-wpr-xperf.aspx).

More information on using the Windows Peformance Toolkit can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/11/23/wpr-xperf-capture-high-cpu-disk-i-o-file-registry-networking-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-paged-pool-nonpaged-pool-and-or-application-slowness.aspx), [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-23-Windows-8-SDK) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-29-WinDbg-ETW-Logging). You may need to download the high quality versions of the videos rather than watching them online in order to see the detail on the screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious culprit is a virus, spyware, or some other malicious software. Scan your system regularly with a good spy-catching program such as Lavasoft's Ad-Aware or Patrick M. Kolla's Spybot Search & Destroy. They're free, so why not download and use both of them? Next, update your antivirus definitions and run a full virus scan. Set your antivirus program to check for updates and do a full scan automatically at least once a week.

If virus and spyware scans don't find the problem, it may be due to a malware program that's too new to be caught. More likely, however, is an unintended problem with an honest program.

If your system's CPU spike is constant, the software at fault probably loads when Windows boots. Select Start, Run
, type msconfig, and press Enter. Click the Startup
tab, uncheck suspicious options one at a time, and reboot until the problem stops. Windows 2000 lacks this utility; for this OS, download Startup Control Panel, Mike Lin's free alternative.

If the processor overload occurs intermittently, note what you're doing each time the system slows down: the programs you're running, the Web sites you visited that day, and so on. This information may give you a clue.

In Windows XP and 2000, the Task Manager can show you what's chewing up CPU cycles. Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete (in Windows 2000, click Task Manager
). Choose Processes
to see your running programs and subroutines. The CPU column shows the available CPU cycles that each process is running. You can easily find the problem here. The Performance tab shows your CPU usage. Hover the cursor over the Task Manager icon in your system tray to see the current CPU usage in a pop-up window.

Keep the System Idle Process running, even if it's huge. This process shows the percentage of CPU cycles that are not in use, so in this case, the bigger, the better.

Once you've found the processor glutton, get rid of that program. If it's something you can't do without, determine whether an updated version with a bug fix is available, or look for a competing program that does a better job.

Comment: Actually I reinstalled windows 7 and before posting this question. I'm sure that the system is clear.

Comment: Hi please check your Hard disk it may be problem i think check this link `http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors`

Comment: The most likely cause is a misbehaving device which is constantly causing interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, in task manager, show all processes and sort by CPU. This happened to me before and it was because of a virtual machine instance. Once I closed that instance the CPU usage dropped back down to normal.

Answer (score -1):

You may installed unwanted software's that might run your CPU always.

So try to remove the Unwanted Software's.

Or else you can press CTRL+ALT+DEL and on Processes tab. you can select the unwanted and then click end process to remove.

and the CPU usage will be low.. then only you can perform faster....

Comment: which process would you recommend to terminate based on the provided screenshot?